# convert XML to ruby hash with attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

***Objective :***

Convert XML to ruby Hash , with all node and attributes values

***What i tried :***

```
xml  = 
  '<test id="appears">
    <comment id="doesnt appear">
      it worked
    </comment>
    <comment>
     see!
    </comment>
    <comment />
  </test>'

hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

Now i get this  hash

```
#=>{"test"=>{"id"=>"appears", "comment"=>["it worked", "see!", nil]}}
```

Notice how the id attribute on the first comment element doesn't appear.

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution  here is the gem

```
gem 'cobravsmongoose', '~> 0.0.2'
```

Try this ,

```
  hash =CobraVsMongoose.xml_to_hash(xml)
```

here is result :

```
{"test"=>{"@id"=>"appears", "comment"=>[{"@id"=>"doesnt appear", "$"=>"it worked"}, {"$"=>"see!"}, {}]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's problem with active support XMLConverter class
Please add following code to any of your initializers file.

```
module ActiveSupport
    class XMLConverter
        private
            def become_content?(value)
                value['type'] == 'file' || (value['__content__'] && (value.keys.size == 1 && value['__content__'].present?))
            end
    end
end
```

It will gives you output like following.

Ex Input XML

```
xml = '<album>
   <song-name type="published">Do Re Mi</song-name>
</album>'

Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

Output will be

```
{"album"=>{"song_name"=>{"type"=>"published", "__content__"=>"Do Re Mi"}}}
```