# Why does converting Nokogiri XML to JSON with Hash#from_xml remove content?

Tags: ruby, json, xml, nokogiri

In converting a Nokogiri object to XML and then to JSON, the majority of the content dissapears.

**Code getting the data and converting:**

```
def get_data
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("<url>", "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}"))

  # Get interesting block of HTML
  blurb = doc.css('.entry')

  # Convert Nokogiri object to XML
  xmlBlurb = blurb.to_xml

  # Convert to JSON
  jsonBlurb = Hash.from_xml(xmlBlurb).to_json

  return jsonBlurb 
end
```

Somehow between `xmlBlurb` and `jsonBlurb`, I'm going from 10+ lines of XML, to a single JSON object `{ attr: content }` with only 1 attribute.

I know there are several questions on SO regarding converting XML to JSON but none that I read address this specific issue.

Does anyone know what can cause the loss of data?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input XML and the JSON output you're expecting. Also, what is `Hash.from_xml`? It's not a standard Ruby method, nor does it come from Nokogiri.

Comment: Your title is misleading. Converting XML to JSON doesn't lose content, your code is losing content. Read "[mcve]". Your code doesn't demonstrate the problem and you're missing minimal sample input required to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hash#from_xml` is an addition to the standard library Hash class made by Rails.  This method is documented as troublesome in losing attributes under various conditions during the conversion from XML to Hash.

"[convert XML to ruby hash with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380935/convert-xml-to-ruby-hash-with-attributes)" provides some suggestions.

Sources:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/588
- https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1598-preserve-xml-attributes-with-hashfrom_xml-and-activeresource
- http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/from_xml/class